# Failed to construct kafka producer after dependency update

Tags: java, spring-kafka, dependency-management

In my SpringBoot Java project I'm using kafka, in particular ReactiveKafka. I was updating dependencies, in particular these one:

1. springboot 2.6.6 -> 3.1.5
2. spring-kafka 2.8.0 -> 3.0.11
3. reactor-kafka 1.3.13 -> 1.3.20
4. java version 17
   After the update I get this error (which wasn't thrown before the update):

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
```

and going down the stacktrace, the root cause is:

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule
```

Is there something about dependencies version not compatible?
I checked in intellij with the dependency analizer, but all dependencies using kafka use the same version
[All kafka dependencies here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrdZU.png)
This is my code in the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    private KafkaProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaProducerConfiguration(KafkaProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> kafkaProducerTemplate() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        return new ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<>(SenderOptions.create(producerProps));
    }

}
```

My properties in application.yml looks like this:

```
spring:
  ...
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: my-bootstrap-server
    ssl:
      protocol: TLSv1.2
    properties:
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl.mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
      sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="my_user" password="my_password";
      ssl.enabled.protocols: TLSv1.2
      ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: HTTPS
    producer:
      client-id: my-client
```

By looking at this error here on overflow, I tried adding
`Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());`
before the return, but I still get the error.
I also tried setting the ContextClassLoader to null, nothing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that SSL configuration, but this might be helpful: https://medium.com/@hussein.joe.au/kafka-authentication-using-sasl-scram-740e55da1fbc

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to config :

```
@Configuration
```

public class KafkaConfig {

```
@Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

}

and for the producer  :

```
  @Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Message> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Message> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

PS : i am working with an external object not a string